# Using SVN for the first time

Tags: macos, svn

Not sure if I should be asking here or Server Fault.

Anyhow, I recently started a project at a new job that has SVN installed. I didn't use it even though I was given SSH access with some keygen thing. But now I've done some reading online for beginner's and I'm having a tough time getting past "which svn" after I input a command through SSH. I guess that tells me the path to the repository (which is /usr/bin/svn) but I don't even know how to get to that directory (I'm using Terminal on Mac OS X).

All this makes me feel pretty stupid, since I've never really had to use the terminal to do web projects before and this is my first experience with SVN via SSH (Hell, first time using SSH even).

I have been googling and reading for a weekend now, but I figured someone on here probably has a good idea of where to find the files or to check which are under SVN etc. I think my main problem is finding out how to use the terminal to "get" to the folder I want to be working on.

I did read up on the commands to check if a file is under SVN, check out, update, commit, etc. I would just like to know how to get to these files to do that. Sorry for the noob question and thanks in advance

Bonus points if someone explains the benefits of SSH (I totally understand the benefits of SVN and would love to learn it properly)

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use a SVN client? eg http://versionsapp.com/ or http://www.zennaware.com/cornerstone/index.php

Comment: Well I didn't know that... Thanks! Honestly, searching "SVN", etc. on google is not very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely better off using a subversion client. Two of the most popular ones for OS X are http://versionsapp.com and http://zennaware.com/cornerstone/index.php (lately my dev friends seem to like cornerstone more.)

These should let you do all (or nearly all) SVN functions, but by using a GUI. You'll still want to learn the terminology. Take a look at http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.basic.html

You want SVN+SSH as it's more secure, but that shouldn't mean you have to use the command line.

Comment: Yeah, I asked around (something I should've done earlier). Cornerstone definitely seems the way to go. Thanks, buddy

Answer (score 0):

Well there is no need to go to the `/usr/bin` even though `svn` resides there. `/usr/bin` is a standard location which is automatically included when the system tries to resolve the location of a file. You should be able to just start using SVN commands like:

```
svn checkout ...
```

The benefits of using SVN and SSH are separate questions all together.

Comment: I'm not sure which directories/files are under SVN -- Is there a handy way to check that?

Answer (score 0):

`svn list --verbose http://host_name/svn_dir` will give you a list of the current versioned projects (including revision number and modified date)

`svn checkout http://host_name/svn_dir/repository_name projectx` will checkout the repo (creating a working copy on your local machine)

I'd recommend the manual [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/), even if you don't read it to start with and just use it as your first reference point when needed.